# Access Global not working

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a  Global Variable called EmployeeID. I set this by calling a function:

```
   Global EmployeeID As Integer
   Public Sub init_Globals(emp As Integer)
       EmployeeID = emp
    End Sub
```

On the main form, I used:

```
MsgBox EmployeeID
```

from a button and it works just fine; but the funny thing is when I use this from a subform it returns a 0:
I might add that this is a Continuous Form as well.

```
Private Sub cboWhichDate_AfterUpdate()
    Me.txtEmployee = EmployeeID
End Sub
```

Comment: Where and how is `EmployeeID` declared?

Comment: it is declared from at the point of login. Call init_Globals(emp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "global" variable can only be "global" if its scope is global. Sticking a `Global` access modifier to a field declared in a class module doesn't make it global.

In fact, the `Global` keyword is deprecated, and is completely replaced/superseded by the `Public` access modifier.

What matters is the variable's *scope*. If that declaration is located in a class module (a form's code-behind *is* essentially a class module), then all you've done is declare a public instance field; you can only access the value via the object instance that owns it.

```
Dim MyObject As New MyForm
MyObject.EmployeeID = 42

MsgBox MyObject.EmployeeID
```

To make a global variable, add a standard module (.bas) to your project, and declare it there.

```
Public EmployeeID As Integer
```

Now everyone everywhere can access `EmployeeID`, because it's *scoped* to a *module* (i.e. not an *instance of an object*), and its *accessibility* is public.

That said, global variables are evil and can easily lead to unmaintainable spaghetti code; Consider passing values as parameters instead.